# Functions stored in variables? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Could somebody please explain what this notation is in javascript? What is function(d) doing? In this program it seemse that x is called by the following, but I have no idea what any of this means. Thanks in advance...

```
x = function(d) { return d.x * width / mx; };

// later....
 x({x: .9}); // call
```

Comment: The syntax is invalid, the last line is missing a `)`. For the function syntax, have a look at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.9 is a value of the property x of the object(d) being passed into the function.

In the function, d = {x:9}(object) , now when you ask for d's property(x) Value (using DOT notation), it returns the value for the property x.

so d.x returns 0.9!

So you would ask me how did i pass the value of the  property into the function-X in the first place, well thats what we did when we dis this ->  x(objectBeingSent); where objectBeingSent is {x: .9}.

Anonymous functions are functions that are dynamically declared at
 runtime. They’re called anonymous functions because they aren’t given
 a name in the same way as normal functions.

Anonymous functions are declared using the function operator. You can
 use the function operator to create a new function wherever it’s valid
 to put an expression. For example you could declare a new function as
 a parameter to a function call or to assign a property of another
 object.

The function operator returns a reference to the function that was
 just created. The function can then be assigned to a variable, passed
 as a parameter or returned from another function. This is possible
 because functions are first class objects in javascript.

Here’s an example where a function is declared in the regular way
 using the function statement:

```
 function eatCake(){
     alert("So delicious and moist");
 }
 eatCake();
```

Here’s an example where the same function is declared dynamically
 using the function operator:

```
 var eatCakeAnon = function(){
     alert("So delicious and moist");
 };
 eatCakeAnon();
```

See the semicolon after the second function's closing bracket? **};**
You use a semi-colon after a statement. This is a statement:

```
var eatCakeAnon = function(){
         alert("So delicious and moist");
     };
```

[Source](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/)

P.S. Best explanantion that i could find!

Comment: ok, but could you please explain how the method is being called above? What is the parameter doing with the x : .9? Thanks!

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala No need for the second semicolon in the first example

Comment: .9 is a property of the object(d) being passed into the function.

In the function, d = {x:9}(object) , now when you ask for d's property named x(using DOT notation), it returns the property x.

so d.x returns 0.9!

Comment: @Mageek thanks mate, should have placed just for the statement in the second example. Edited and explained.

Comment: -1: `.9` is NOT a property of any object. It is a number literal that is the same as `0.9`. `.9` is the value of property `x` of the object.

Comment: @trinithis Thanks for pointing that out. I was thinking completely in the current objects context(some thing like if person.name= Pname, then thinking of Pname as teh person's name itself for the life of the object) and ignored the fact that .9 is indeed the value of the propery, but not the property itself. I edited the explanation.

Comment: @trinithis: Answer fixed, can you please consider removing down vote now :)

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala: I would, but SO burned my vote in. I thought you could revote after a post was updated. Huh.

Comment: Is there any performance benefit when storing a function inside a variable?

Answer (score 1):

It's called an anonymous function. The function takes an object in the form of {x: *number*} as an argument and does some math on *number*.